# Parsing array within XML result

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

I am having trouble understanding the proper syntax to print array results using the SimpleXMLElement. From my xml result i must ask the user to match themselves with one of the people found in the array, and am not sure what is the best way to do this.

Sample XML result:

```
[authentication] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [age] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [code] => 5
                [ambiguous] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [person] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Paul  Foreman
                                        [question] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => dcalc3
                                                [prompt] => What+do+the+%3Cb%3Elast+four%3C%2Fb%3E+digits+of+your+Social+Security+Number+add+up+to%3F
                                                [answer] => 5
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Paul  Foreman
                                        [question] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => dcalc3
                                                [prompt] => What+do+the+%3Cb%3Elast+four%3C%2Fb%3E+digits+of+your+Social+Security+Number+add+up+to%3F
                                                [answer] => 6
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Solution im looking for:

```
<?php
$string = $xml_result;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$is_age_code = $xml->authentication->{'age'}->code;

if($x_is_age_code == '5'){
// code 5 means more than one match found
    // Ask user verification question
        // If answer matches question
               // Set current user as that person
}
?>
```

How can i find out how many 'Persons' are in the array and identify them with a number?

Comment: So given your example XML, the number you are looking for would be 2? Because there are 2 persons in the array `$xml->authentication->age->ambiguous->person`? Then you could use `count($xml->authentication->age-> ambiguous->person)`.

Comment: I see ok thanks, but how do i echo the question prompt? $xml->authentication->{'age'}->ambiguos->{'person'}->question->{'prompt'} doesnt work neither does $xml->authentication->{'age'}->ambiguos->{'person'}->0->{'question'}->prompt

Comment: Try `$xml->authentication->age->ambiguous->person[0]->question->prompt`. As `person` is an array, you have to use it as an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of persons use:

```
echo count($xml->authentication->age->ambiguous->person);
```

To access the subnodes of a person use

```
echo $xml->authentication->age->ambiguous->person[0]->question->prompt;
```

or with a loop:

```
foreach ($xml->authentication->age->ambiguous->person as $person) {
    echo $person->question->prompt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, that helped me write my own logic for it using the loop.